# Using regex modification only in a selected part of a text

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
s = "In $ \mathcal{N}=4$ we fix them completely through the duality to null"
```

Imagine I am doing some text cleaning with the following command:

```
new_s = s.replace('(', ' ')
new_s = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', new_s)
```

Is there a way to modify all the string except what is in the $ $ ?

Thanks

Comment: How about doing it in three steps? 1. Extract text b/w $ $ and save in a list 2. Apply the regex 3. Substitute back from list in 1

Comment: If my text is very long and there are many $equations$, how could I do that efficiently? I am not very proficient in regex so excuse me if I might be confused

Comment: The method I suggested sounds quite inefficient, but here are some more details. Assuming you're only confused about step 1, here's how I suggest it can be done: a) write a separate regex to match $equation$ b) search for all occurrences of this regex in string and replace with a suitable placeholder, while storing the matches in a list. This would complete step 1. For step 3, you just need to keep matching the placeholder from 'b)' and replacing values from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` directly with a method as replacement:

```py
regex = re.compile(r'(\$[^$]*\$)|[^\x00-\x7F]+|\(')
print(regex.sub(lambda m: m.group(1) or " ", s))
```

See [proof online](https://tio.run/##NY1Ba8IwHEfv/RQ/SqDJ1OLYYDDoVfDiFzAKsf5tA0kT0hQrutu@0U47i5@rtoMd34PH85dYu@ZtGLT1LkQESloUSNcNGLi0KtalMtfNV/Eu8Pi9/zy@Gc6Ek@4Ra7IonfWGIpnLyMF1VT15HDtldBydA286Y/7jNAlUUT8uAuVTqw3xkHHJtnu2e5FM3LZ72S@XC9l/rHazm@SZSHzQTeR/Zd52B26UPRwV7CdsXo1Tz18FXECKdI5WiGF4Ag)

**What does it do**

1. `(\$[^$]*\$)|[^\x00-\x7F]+|\(` captures all between two dollar symbols into capturing group with ID 1 with `(\$[^$]*\$)`, and matches all non-ASCII or `(` characters with `[^\x00-\x7F]+|\(` without capturing.
2. If the first alternative matches, nothing is replaced in the string (since `m.group(1)` puts back what was matched) and otherwise, the replacement is a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\$).+(?=\$)
```

By using lookaround regex, we can match all the contents inside `$ ... $`.

```py
import re

s = "In $ \mathcal{N}=4$ we fix them completely through the duality to null"
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=\$).+(?=\$)', re.M)

# returns you the string containing 
# only the contents inside $ ... $
s = ' '.join(map(str.strip, regex.findall(s)))
print(s)
```

Know more about lookaround operators [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thank you! How could we select everything else, since I don't want to change what is inside the $$

Comment: @lalaland can you please explain me in details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a lot of scientific abstracts, and I want to classify the documents based on the topics. In order to do that  I need to clean the abstracts before applying tf-idf. the abstracts contain formulas (which are between $$  - LaTex equation mode). I want to clean the abstracts but preserving the formulas, to give me extra power when classifying

Comment: @lalaland like you wanna remove everything from the string except what's inside in `$ ... $` right?

Comment: every noise. for instance punctuation, \n, non-ascii characters...